# Closure of intersection of convex sets

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $C_i$ be a convex set in $R^n$ for $i\in I$, suppose sets $ri \, C_i$ have at least one point in common, then how to prove this:

$cl\bigcap\{C_i\mid i\in I\} = \bigcap\{cl \, C_i \mid i\in I\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true.

$(0,1)$ and $(1,2)$ are convex sets in $\Bbb R^1$. Their intersection (and its closure) is empty, but their closures intersect in $\{1\}$.

Comment: your counterexample is right. If I add the condition suppose sets $ri\, C_i$ have at least one point in common, how to prove the theorem?

Answer (score 0):

Let A,B convex sets such that $\operatorname{ri}(A)\bigcap \operatorname{ri}(B) \neq \varnothing$. Then:

($\Rightarrow$) $A \subset \bar{A}$ and $B \subset \bar{B}$ implies $A\bigcap B \subset \bar{A}\bigcap \bar{B}$. But $\ \bar{A}\bigcap \bar{B}$ is closed, so $\overline{A \bigcap B} \subset \bar{A}\bigcap \bar{B}$.

($\Leftarrow$) Take $x \in \operatorname{ri}(A)\bigcap \operatorname{ri}(B)$ and $y \in \bar{A}\bigcap \bar{B}$. By the accessibility lemma (applying in both), $[x, y[ = \{x \lambda + (1 - \lambda)y: 0 < \lambda \leq 1 \} \subset \operatorname{ri}(A)\bigcap \operatorname{ri}(B) \subset A \bigcap B$. In special, if $\lambda = \frac{1}{n}$, then:

$$z_{n} = \left[\frac{x}{n} + \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)y\right] \in A \bigcap B, \ \forall n \in \mathrm{N}$$

How $z_{n} \longrightarrow y$, when $n \longrightarrow \infty$, $y$ is a limit point of $A \bigcap B$. Therefore, $y \in \overline{A \bigcap B}$.

So, $ \bar{A}\bigcap \bar{B} \subset \overline{A \bigcap B}$.